# How to overwrite value from .properties file?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Application read master password from externalized `credentials.properties` file:

```
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("file:${user.home}/.app/credentials.properties"),
        @PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
})
```

Application properties `application.properties`:

```
spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties@
```

is loaded from `application-{PROFILE}.properties` file for active profile.

How to overwrite settings located in `file:${user.home}/.app/credentials.properties` but only for specific profile (develop)?

I would change the setting value in IDE and not in filesystem.

Comment: Why not use an environment variable? Those override whatever is in properties files and are easy to set up via IDE in your local environment.

Comment: Because there is a reason for it to be in the file.

Comment: What about including an additional [optional] property file with higher priority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config), config data, such as `application.properties` and `application-develop.properties` files, always takes precedence over `@PropertySource`.

> Spring Boot uses a very particular PropertySource order that is
> designed to allow sensible overriding of values. Later property
> sources can override the values defined in earlier ones. Sources are
> considered in the following order:
>
> 1. Default properties (specified by setting
>    `SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties`).
> 2. `@PropertySource` annotations on your `@Configuration` classes.
> 3. Config data (such as `application.properties` files).
>
>    ...

Hence, any value specified in `application-develop.properties` will override the corresponding value in `credentials.properties`.